# Increase width of tabularx column

Tags: tabularx

Community,

I want to increase the width of a column because the text in the second row makes a new line. When I use p{x.xcm} there is no more centering of the content below.

[image: Picture of table]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
 l
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
}
   \toprule
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{Probe}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Brechungsindex} & 
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Volumen/mL} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Masse/g} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Stoffmenge/mol} 
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{vol\%} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{mol\%}\\
   \cmidrule{2-18}
   & A-reich & B-reich & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C\\
   \midrule
   P1 & 1.4242 & 1.4242 & 42   & 42   & 42   & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42  & 42 & 42 
   & 42  & 42 & 42\\
   P3 & 1.4242 & 1.4242 & 42   & 42   & 42   & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42  & 42 & 42 
   & 42  & 42 & 42\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

The table is also in a sideways environment because it is so large.

Thank you in advance.

Greetings FH

Comment: You could try to replace the first two occurrences of `>{\centering}` with two `c`

Comment: Since you don't need linebreaks in your cells, I suggest entirely switching from `tabularx` to `tabular`or `tabular*` if you want to make sure yor table is as wide as the current linewidth. Additionally, I would suggest using `siunitx` for the units and in order to align the numbers in the table columns.

Comment: I would also replace `\cmidrule{2-18}` with `\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-15} \cmidrule(l){16-18}`

Comment: Thank you for the advice I also like the separated lines very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion based on `tabular*` instead of `tabularx`.

[image]

Depending on the contents of the columns, you might want to consider using `siunitx` in order to align the numbers with respect to their decimal separator. `siunitx` also comes in handy for the units in your column headers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{17}{c}}
   \toprule
   Probe 
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Brechungsindex} 
       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Volumen/mL} 
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Masse/g} 
           & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Stoffmenge/mol} 
             & \multicolumn{3}{c}{vol\%} 
               & \multicolumn{3}{c}{mol\%}\\
   \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-12} \cmidrule(lr){13-15} \cmidrule(l){16-18}
   & A-reich & B-reich & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C & A & B & C\\
   \midrule
   P1 & 1.4242 & 1.4242 & 42   & 42   & 42   & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42  & 42 & 42 
   & 42  & 42 & 42\\
   P3 & 1.4242 & 1.4242 & 42   & 42   & 42   & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42    & 42   & 42 & 42  & 42 & 42 
   & 42  & 42 & 42\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Wulle suggested: replacing the first two `>{\centering}` with `c` did the job.

Thank you Wulle